# How can I reload swayidle / swaylock?

Tags: screensaver, sway

In my `.sway/config`, I have

```
exec swayidle -w \
        timeout 30 'swaylock -f -c 000000' \
        timeout 30 'swaymsg "output * dpms off"' \
                resume 'swaymsg "output * dpms on"' \
        before-sleep 'swaylock -f -c 000000'
```

Let's say I decide that I want to increase that timeout, so I make it,

```
exec swayidle -w \
        timeout 180 'swaylock -f -c 000000' \
        timeout 180 'swaymsg "output * dpms off"' \
                resume 'swaymsg "output * dpms on"' \
        before-sleep 'swaylock -f -c 000000'
```

How can I reload these settings? Moreover, when I try to `killall swayidle` and run this command manually, I get

```
Failed to find session name: PID 8472 does not belong to any known session
No command specified! Nothing to do, will exit
```

How can I get `swayidle` running with updated timeouts?

Answer (score 2):

I use a script and it works just fine. Maybe this approach would help. Here's the relevant section of my lock script 'mylock':

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

[[ "$SWAYSOCK" ]] && {
    TIMEOUT=600

    BACKGROUND_COLLECTION=~/.fluxbox/backgrounds
    BACKGROUND=$( ls $BACKGROUND_COLLECTION | shuf -n 1)
    case "$1" in
        lock-now)
            BG='&'
            [[ "$2" == "wait" ]] && BG=''
            swaylock -f --image "$BACKGROUND_COLLECTION/$BACKGROUND" $BG
            ;;

        lock-off)
            pkill swayidle
            swayidle -w \
                timeout $TIMEOUT  "swaymsg 'output * dpms off'" \
                resume            "swaymsg 'output * dpms on'" \
                before-sleep      "mylock lock-now wait; mylock enable-lock" &
            rofi -width 20 -e "screen lock disabled"
            ;;

        enable-lock|*)
            pkill swayidle
            swayidle -w \
                timeout $TIMEOUT                "swaymsg 'output * dpms off'"  resume "swaymsg 'output * dpms on'" \
                timeout $(( TIMEOUT * 2 ))      "swaymsg 'output * dpms on'; mylock lock-now" \
                timeout $(( TIMEOUT * 3 ))      "swaymsg 'output * dpms off'" resume "swaymsg 'output * dpms on'" \
                timeout $(( TIMEOUT * 4 ))      "sudo systemctl suspend" \
                before-sleep                    "mylock lock-now wait" &
            ;;
    esac

    #ps -ef |grep '[s]wayidle'
    exit $?
}
```

... and then this in sway config:

```
set $a Mod1
set $mod Mod4
set $c Control
set $s Shift
...
bindsym $a+$c+l    exec mylock lock-now
bindsym $mod+l     exec mylock lock-now
bindsym $s+$a+$c+l exec mylock lock-off
bindsym $s+$mod+l  exec mylock lock-off
```

This allows fairly complex and dynamic locking behaviour:

- on timeout X secs, screen blanks
- on timeout 2X secs, screen locks and displays a random photo
- on timeout 3X, screen blanks again (but remains locked).

I also wanted to be able to turn off the locking eg if I'm at home, not worried about security but bothered by having to unlock all the time - I just press Shift-$mod-L.

But - when I suspend the laptop I want the original locking to apply (otherwise I'm likely to forget to restore it when I go to sleep or grab the laptop and go out).

If I want to manually lock the laptop 'now', then just $mod-L.

(zenity is optional for visual feedback of lock-off operation).

I hope you can adapt this approach for your use-case.

Answer (score 2):

To use any new changes done to the sway config, you just need to reload it. Default shortcut should be <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. But you can of course modify it to your taste in you sway config. E.g.:

```
# Reload the configuration file
bindsym Mod4+R reload
```

This would set the reload action on <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. Just don't forget to reload it first with the previous shortcut.

EDIT: Just noticed, that this actually doesn't reload swayidle (or anything else that is run by `exec`). To reload such programs you can however manually kill them (e.g. by running `killall swayidle`) and then temporarily change the command in your sway config to `exec_always` and reload the config. Just don't forget to change it back to just `exec` later, otherwise you'll get new instance of swayidle everytime you reload the config in future.